# Python find and replace in string based on a mapping dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, string, dictionary, replace, find

I have a string

```
str = "abcdef"
```

and a mapping

```
map = {'a':'b','b':'c', 'c':'d'}
```

The expected output is

```
out_str = 'bcddef'
```

How can I apply mapping in one iteration in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
s = "abcdef"
m = {"a": "b", "b": "c", "c": "d"}

print("".join(m.get(ch, ch) for ch in s))
```

Prints:

```
bcddef
```